# Yandex forbidden error when I am not using it

Tags: c#, asp.net, yandex

I am getting the following error:

> GET
>   http://bs.yandex.ru/informer/29840004/3_1_FFFFFFFF_EFEFEFFF_0_pageviews
>   403 (Forbidden)

The weird thing is that I am not using yandex and I don´t know from where I am calling to yandex. This is making me to fail some js code because it is just not executing anymore. I am using jquery-1.9.2.min.js and I search in the whole project but I didn´t found yandex anywhere